# how to use for loop in asynchronous methods of parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to call functions of parse.com in for loop, but when I put functions into for loop then for loop gets completed without response from functions.

```
for (var i = 0; i <tourPackage.length; i++) { 
        var Apackage = tourPackage[i].attributes;  
        tourPackageDest.set("package_id",tourPackage[i].id);
       tourPackageDest.set("itinerary",Apackage.holiday_short_detail);
        var SD = Apackage.destination.split(',');
            for(var k=0; k<SD.length;k++){
                var destPlace =                           Parse.Object.extend("Cities_World");//DestinationMaster
                 var query = new Parse.Query(destPlace);
                query.equalTo("place_name", SD[k]);
                query.find().then(function(results){
                    console.log(results);
                });
                tourPackageDest.save(null,{
                    success: function(Tpackage){
                        console.log("Successfully saved in PackageItineraryMaster");
                        }
                });
            }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of those methods you're calling (e.g., .find(), .save()) are asynchronous. From the looks of it, you're writing the code as if they as synchronous methods. Here is an example ([via the Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-parallel)) of how to structure your code to account for this asynchronicity:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Comments");
query.equalTo("post", 123);

query.find().then(function(results) {
  // Collect one promise for each delete into an array.
  var promises = [];
  _.each(results, function(result) {
    // Start this delete immediately and add its promise to the list.
    promises.push(result.destroy());
  });
  // Return a new promise that is resolved when all of the deletes are finished.
  return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

}).then(function() {
  // Every comment was deleted.
});
```

Basically, you want to add each of the promises from the async functions to an array and create a new promise that resolves when all those promises are resolved.

Comment: Thank you Thank you thank you, I am just newbie in parse.com so taking time to resolve problems. But you make it more simpler for me. Thanks Again